# Programmatically checking if email is delivered to outgoing SMTP server

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I am supporting an application that I think is sporadically loosing email messages. The application sends thousands of email, and I am regularly getting cases from uses saying they didn't get notifications. I am trying to find a reproducible pattern so I can get the issue looked into.

I want to know if there is a way to query the SMTP server and ask what messages it has been asked to send. I don't want a read receipt I just want to check that the application is successfully passing the email to the outgoing SMTP server.

Can I query the outgoing SMTP server to get a list of messages it has sent or a list of requests it has recieved to send messages?

Comment: Low tech approach is just set up your own email, and cc yourself in, i don't think you can query an outgoing smpt server though some may have logging

Comment: unfortunately the error only happens in production and the systems sends about 6000 emails a day. I don't want to have to try and filter through 6000 emails I want to just be able to monitor a few key areas where I suspect the error is more likely to occur.

Comment: Depend on your smtp server. Most of them support us to see the log on it and support to check the status of the outgoing email. Double check with your smtp provider.